# How to use -a +b input operations

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem I have is when I enter an input such as: `-6+7`, the answer is

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'

I'm not sure what's the problem. Please help.

I am trying to make an arithmetic operation in order to be able to input `a-b` or `-a+b` and get the answer. Thank you.

```
operation = input('Enter an arithmetic operation: ')
print(operation)
operation = operation.replace(" ", "")
a = float(operation[0])
b = float(operation[2])
sign = operation[1]

if(sign == '+'):
    sum = a + b
    print(sum)
elif(sign == '-'):
    sum = a - b
    print(sum)
elif(sign == '*'):
    sum = a * b
    print(sum)
elif(sign == '/'):
    sum = a / b
    print(round(sum, 3))
```

Comment: You have 4 characters in your string, but you're only dealing with 3. The value of `a` will be `-`, which cannot be converted to a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `-6+7` this input, `operation` is look like : `operation[0] = -`, `operation[1] = 6`, `operation[2] = +`,  `operation[3] = 7`, all they are in string form, for getting `a` and `b` you need to use right index of `operation`.

For example you can have two sign and work on them according to the sign, as the input will have two sign you need to consider both of them in your code,  like :

```
operation = input('Enter an arithmetic operation: ')
print(operation)
operation = operation.replace(" ", "")
a = float(operation[1])
b = float(operation[3])
sign1 = operation[0]
sign2 = operation[2]


# now work according to sign1 and sign2
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i tried to do so and now i can do -a+b. but i lost the ability to do a+b because operation[1] would be the +, so I'm confused on how to make it work both ways.

Comment: You should fixed the input pattern like `-6+7` style,  or can check the input string size, when the size is 4 then use one way and when the input size is 3 use another way. By this you can fix the problem i hope.

Comment: Alhamdulillah, worked like a charm. I'm so happy. thanks a lot. Allah be with you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when you enter '-6+7' as input, your 'operation[0]' is '-' and your 'operation[2]' is '+'. Therefore, the error.

Answer (score 0):

`operation[0]` is the sign, not the first value. You're trying to convert the sign to a float which can't be done.

For any `operation[x]` where each val is one digit:

0 = first sign

1 = first val

2 = second sign / binary operator

3 = second val

Comment: mmm screwed up the indices by not starting at 0. my bad